# db2 sql does not return minimum value when using min

Tags: db2

SELECT MIN(NO_PLAYERS) FROM TEAM
**the output is 10**

but in the table, the minimum value is 2.

the table:

[TABLE TEAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4rhu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that column is defined as text filed (char,varchar). Use to_number function to convert from text to number.

select min(to_number(NO_PLAYERS)) FROM TEAM